# Не работает on_message

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

Код:

```
import config
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.message_content = True

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='r!', intents=intents) 

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print("Bot ready!")
@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    print("on_message")
    if message.author == bot.user:
        print("Sender is not user")
        if message.channel.id == 1126833110605103194:
            print("Channel is 1126833110605103194")
            await message.channel.send(message.content)
@bot.command()
async def ping(ctx):
    await ctx.send('pong')


bot.run("token")
```

Логи бота после сообщения в нужном канале:

```
2023-07-07 19:23:51 INFO     discord.client logging in using static token
2023-07-07 19:23:52 INFO     discord.gateway Shard ID None has connected to Gateway (Session ID: 8863fa4af4fff98408ffb50ca612686c).
Bot ready!
```

Что делать?

Answer (score 0):

Исправил

````
@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == bot.user: return;
    else:
        if message.channel.id == 1125491680628453476:
            print("on_message\nChannel is 1126833110605103194")
            await message.channel.send(message.content)```
````

Comment: Не работает так же всё

Comment: Прям скопировал и вставил? У меня всё работает, в консоль пишет спокойно. Напиши что именно ты хочешь от кода? Данный код, после отправки, повторяет ваше сообщение с канала в дискорд. Запустите бота, напишите в ваш канал. В добавку я изменил айди в if message.channel.id == {id channel}, вставьте свой.

Comment: Аааа надо будет проверить. Но у меня суде по всему не вызывается on_message я проверю ваш код (я поменять id канала забыл) и напишу.

Comment: Не работает от слова вообще

Comment: Сможешь написать в дискорд? @celebrity_s
Я скину фулл код. Или мне скинь, я погляжу.